# colorbar numbers erased automatically

Tags: matplotlib, plot

I am plotting a matrix using `imshow` but very strangely one of the plots does not show the numbers in the colorbar scale.

My code is the following:

```
Ndim = 30; t = 1.0; mu = 0.0; Delta = 0.3
u=2.2; g=1.0
filename = "datafile"
delta = read1col(filename)
delta_matrix = np.flipud(np.reshape(delta,(Ndim, Ndim)))
plt.imshow(delta_matrix, aspect='auto')
plt.colorbar()
plt.title(r"$\Delta$")
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.savefig('delta_Ndim%dt%.2fmu%.2fDelta%.2fu%.2fg%.2f.pdf'%(Ndim, t, mu, Delta, u, g))
plt.show()
plt.clf()
```

The strange thing is that other sets of parameters the plots are displayed correctly.

Comment: trim this down to a minimal, working example and include an image of your plot.

Comment: I saw what is going on, all my values are around 0.46215533394699476, and they only differ in at most the two last digits.